# when to use this.props.children and why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm reading this file https://github.com/luispcosta/reddit_clone/blob/master/client/components/Main.jsx

and I don't get line 37, where does the this.props.children come from? I know you can pass props like

```
<Component name='alan'/>
```

and you can get name by doing `this.props.name` to get `alan`. But this props.children means?

Answer (score 4):

> In JSX expressions that contain both an opening tag and a closing tag,
>   the content between those tags is passed as a special prop:
>   props.children. There are several different ways to pass children:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx

For example:

```
<Main>
  <p>This is a child element</p>
  <button>So is this</button>
</Main>
```

`this.props.children` in `Main` will be an array of elements.

```
// Main.jsx    
render() {
  return <div>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>;
}
```

Would render

```
<div>
  <p>This is a child element</p>
  <button>So is this</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where does the the html come from?

Answer (score 1):

In react an element in JSX is represented as

```
const elem = (<div id="test"> Hi I am a div. </div>);
```

And there is another alternative way to represent the react element.
So similar element can be represented as -

```
var elem = React.createElement(
    "div",
    { id: "test" },
    " Hi I am a div. "
);
```

`createElement` has following signature :

```
React.createElement(component, props, ...children)
```

Above `...children` means any nested `JSX` elements inside `div`.

Nested elements in itself can be another **react-element** and may be more than one of them.

```
const elem = (<div id="test"> <h1> Hi I am a div. </h1> </div>);
```

**What is props.children?**

The returned **elem** contains light weight object representation.

It has a field called **props** set. This **props** field contains custom attributes passed and reference to nested elements i.e child elements.

Now lets see how it is represented

```js
const elem = (<div id="test">Hi I am a div.</div>);
console.dir(elem);

const elem1 = (<div id="test"> <h1> Hi I am a div. </h1> </div>);
console.dir(elem1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

From the logs we can see that `props` has a property called `children`. So each **parent element** contains immediate reference to its `children`.

```
"props": {
    "id": "test",
    "children": "Hi I am a div."
  }
```

**When can I use props.children?**

When ever you want to get access to children elements in code.
There can be scenario like you want to get access to all of your nested elements.

A simplest example-

You have created a custom button like below -

```js
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button> {this.props.children} </button>;
  }
};

// What ever you pass insede <MyButton> and </MyButton> 
// You can access it inside your MyButton component via {this.props.children}

const elem = (<MyButton> test1 </MyButton>);
              
ReactDOM.render(
  elem,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  
</div>
```

Another scenario could be you want to loop over your nested children and may be passing some other extra props or may just accessing them -

```js
class MyButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
          {this.props.children} 
         </button>
     );
  }
};

class ButtonContainer extends React.Component {
  
    handleClick = () => {
      console.log("Clicked");
    }

    render() {      
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, 
    (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { handleClick: this.handleClick });
    });    
    
        return (
          <div>
             {childrenWithProps} 
         </div>
     );
  }
};


const elem = (
  <ButtonContainer>
       <MyButton> test1 </MyButton>
       <MyButton> test2 </MyButton>
       <MyButton> test3 </MyButton>
 </ButtonContainer>
);


ReactDOM.render(
  elem,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  </div>
```

There are other scenarios as well with **react-router** e.g when route changes you want to get access to your children elements to render them on screen.

I have included working code and example where ever possible. I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Nately does it help you or still have any doubt?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. I will explain by an example
Lets say you have created some component called **ComponentDemo**.
It is used like this:

```
<ComponentDemo>
 // This component can receive some HTML tags here that will be passed as children props for example:
     <div> Hello world</div>
</ComponentDemo>
```

Then,inside **ComponentDemo** render function you can use it as:

```
render(){
 // lets use the HTML tags we passed as children here 
    {this.props.children}
}
```

what will happen?
**ComponentDemo** will render

```
   <div> Hello world</div>
```

which is the value passed by props.children

Answer (score -1):

You can check the [API reference of react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route)

So, it is just the api provided by react-router which is imported in https://github.com/luispcosta/reddit_clone/blob/master/client/routes.js.

```
const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="groups" component={Groups} />
    <Route path="users" component={Users} />
  </Route>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* this will be either <Users> or <Groups> */}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: so this.props.children is actually Groups/Users component?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson Yes. By different path, this.prop.children will be <Route path="groups" component={Groups} /> or <Route path="users" component={Users} />.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson By the way, this is actually the way that react-router works. If your question is where does the this.props.children come from, the answer is this.props.children is passed by react-router library.